# Updating contents of jar file

Tags: java, file, jar

I am trying to add a textfile to an existing jar.

This is how it should work:

- **JarFile A:** when this runs, it will add a textfile inside JarFile B.
- **JarFile B:** when this runs, it will read some configuration options from the textfiel that was added by JarFile A.

Here is the code that JarFileA executes to add a file:

```
public static void updateZipFile(File zipFile, String targetPackage, File[] files) throws IOException {
    // get a temp file
    File tempFile = createTempFile(zipFile.getName(), null);
    // delete it, otherwise you cannot rename your existing zip to it.
    tempFile.delete();

    boolean renameOk = zipFile.renameTo(tempFile);
    if (!renameOk) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not rename the file " + zipFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to " + tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));

    ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        String name = entry.getName();
        boolean notInFiles = true;
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                notInFiles = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (notInFiles) {
            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
            // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
            int len;
            while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
        entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    }
    // Close the streams        
    zin.close();
    for (File file : files) {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(targetPackage + File.separator + file.getName()));
        // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        // Complete the entry
        out.closeEntry();
        in.close();
    }
    // Complete the ZIP file
    out.close();
    tempFile.delete();
}
```

This all works fine on Mac OS X, but in Windows it does not work. It copies the file but JarFileB cant read this newly created file. Maybe the jar gets corrupt?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you manually open the jar b in windows to make sure that the file was added?

Comment: Yess, did it also manually. But no success.